# python - matching user input to list items

Tags: python

I have written something that reads a file line by line(each line has a path to a folder like: C:\test\test)

It gets the path and then searches the path for all the files, puts them into a list and then asks the user which movie they want to search for. This is where im stuck

Im wanting to get the program to take the users input no matter if its lowercase or uppercase and find the matching files and display them in a numbered list to the user

for example: User searches - star wars

i want to display the files found like:

```
1 Star Wars III.mp4
2 Star Wars Return of the Jedi.mp4
```

so basically print the file name.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

I have this so far but im stuck at this part:

```
import os

def find_all():
    list_num = []
    print('\n','='*8,'Current folders saved','='*8)
    with open('movielist.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read().splitlines()
        file.close()
        for i, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
            print('\n',i,item)
            list_num.append(i)

    user_choice = int(input('\nWhat location do you want to search? '))
    if user_choice == 1:
        one = data[0]
        filelist = os.listdir(one)
        movie_name = input('\nWhat movie are you looking for?: ')
        for i, item in enumerate(filelist, start=1):
            print('\n',i,item)
```

so far this just prints all the files in the location.

this is the current output i get:

```
 ======== Current folders saved ========

 1 K:\Movies

 2 D:\Movies_list\Favorites

 What location do you want to search? 2

 What movie are you looking for?: star wars

 1 Hot Fuzz 2007 1080p.mkv

 2 Inglorious basterds 2008 1080p.mkv

 3 Jurassic Park 3 2001 1080p.mkv

 4 Over the Moon 2020 1080p.mkv

 5 Rogue One - A Star Wars Story 2016 1080p.mkv

 6 Shaun of the Dead 2004 1080p.mkv

 7 Star Wars III 1080p.mkv

 8 The Croods A New Age 2020 1080p.mkv

 9 Thor Ragnarok 2017 1080p.mkv
```

Using the star wars example. I would want the program to just display Star Wars III 1080p.mkv and Rogue One - A Star Wars Story 2016 1080p.mkv

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is currently being printed

Comment: `if movie_name.lower() == item.lower()` or safer `if movie_name.lower() in item.lower()` and then user may put `star` and it find all films with `Star Wars` and all with `StarTrek`

Comment: @Ciaran I updated my current output at the bottom

Comment: @furas I will give this a go. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lower()` or `upper()` on both

```
 if movie_name.lower() == item.lower(): 
     print('\n',i,item)
```

or better usin `in` instead of `==`

```
 if movie_name.lower() in item.lower(): 
     print('\n',i,item)
```

and then user may put `Star` and it find all movies with `Star Wars` and all with `StarTrek`

It needs only new variable to enumerate selected movies because `if` will skip titles and then `i` will display wrong number.

```
    movie_name = input('\nWhat movie are you looking for?: ')

    number = 0

    for i, item in enumerate(filelist, start=1):
        if movie_name.lower() in item.lower(): 
            number += 1
            print('\n',number,item)
```

---

For more complex searching you could use `regex` or you could put names in database like `SQLite` and use SQL queries.

With `regex` you could use `star.*jedi` to get only `Star Wars Return of the Jedi`

Comment: Thanks, This helped a lot. Got it working now!

Answer (score 1):

Does this resolve your question?

**Here basically we changing this part of your code:**

```
for i, item in enumerate(filelist, start=1):
            print('\n',i,item)
```

To Be,

```
for i, item in enumerate(filelist, start=1):
    if movie_name.lower() in item.lower():
       print(item)
```

You might notice this line different in the code:

```
if movie_name.lower() in item.lower():
   print(item)
```

**What we are saying here is that the `movie_name` that the user gave, simply just search for it in the text/`item`. And the `.lower()` method that we use here is simply just to ensure that there are no problems with casing.**
So for example if the user gave the input "Fuzz" first of all it be considered as "fuzz" and the elements in the list will be lowercased too, so now the real searching begins It will go through the list looping and searching for the string "fuzz" in the string, like this:

`"fuzz" in "star wars iii.mp4" == False`
`"fuzz" in "hot fuzz 2008 1080p.mkv" == True`

When the code snippet is `True` it will simply print the current item that it was looping on.

Here is the full snippet

```py
import os


def find_all():
    list_num = []
    print('\n', '='*8, 'Current folders saved', '='*8)
    with open('movielist.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read().splitlines()
        file.close()
        for i, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
            print('\n', i, item)
            list_num.append(i)

    user_choice = int(input('\nWhat location do you want to search? '))
    if user_choice:
        num = data[user_choice]
        filelist = os.listdir(num)
        movie_name = input('\nWhat movie are you looking for?: ')
        for i, item in enumerate(filelist, start=1):
            if movie_name.lower() in item.lower():
                print(item)


find_all()
```

Any more queries on this answer are welcome!

Comment: it resolve it (partially) but you coulde describe it

Comment: Sure, will do  @furas

Comment: This works now!. Thanks for your solution!! Helps me a lot :)

Comment: If this helps you you could have upvoted the answer, that helps me alot :)

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I forget to do that sometimes. I have done it now and again thanks :)

Comment: Welcome, @SimpleJay_